# Record field is empty after package update

Tags: trigger, managed-package, sobject

I have custom managed package and created record of sObject(Response__c) from that package with namespace. And after updating package to new version one field(Message__c) became empty. That field is populated in before insert trigger and doesn't have any code that will delete value from it. There were updates in that field, but its only description and I tried to update it again, but value in field is still here. That is, it went like this:
1.Install package
2.Create record
3.Update package
4.Field is empty

Comment: Is there a post install script for the package that does this field reset?

Comment: @PhilW nope, i have checked it